# how to find min max of sum?

Tags: sql-server, select, ms-access

hello everyone i try to find minimum and maximum value of SUM(units_sold) i test some ways but i can't find best solution please help me !

```
    SELECT TOP 1    dp.product_name, SUM(fs.units_sold) AS SumOfunits_sold
    FROM           dim_product dp
    INNER JOIN  fact_sales fs
        ON     dp.product_code = fs.product_code
    GROUP BY
            dp.product_name
    ORDER BY
        SUM(fe.units_sold) DESC
UNION ALL
     SELECT TOP 1     dp.product_name, SUM(fs.units_sold) AS SumOfunits_sold
      FROM   dim_product dp
      INNER JOIN  fact_sales fs
      ON     dp.product_code = fs.product_code
      GROUP BY
             dp.product_name
      ORDER BY
                SUM(fe.units_sold) ACS ;
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong for mysql - the tag removed.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: SQL Server and MS Access are 2 completely different products.  Please tag properly.

Comment: There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to take a look? It's very important to specify the problem as precisely as possible because answers (very) frequently depend on the database server used - SQL **is** a standard, but it's not completely implemented by any RDBMS product and the variations are significant enough that you need to specify which one you are using. Also, some sample data and a desired result would be very helpful - perhaps in the form of a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: thanks all for your advice and help ... really i am new in 'stackexchange ' i don't know the tips and conditions Sorry :)

Comment: Do you want only the sums (min and max), or the sums with the related `product_name`?

Comment: yes i want to find MAX and MIN of the SUM(fs.units_sold) for each product name ,So i want to select product name also ,  the result show me what product name have maximum value or minimum ...... in this form  ... [ product1 - 16   ...  product2 - 9]

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dp.product_name, SUM(fs.units_sold) AS SumOfunits_sold
    FROM   dim_product dp
    INNER JOIN  fact_sales fs ON dp.product_code = fs.product_code
    GROUP BY dp.product_name
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 product_name, SumOfunits_sold 
    FROM cte 
    ORDER BY SumOfunits_sold DESC
) a
UNION
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 product_name, SumOfunits_sold 
    FROM cte 
    ORDER BY SumOfunits_sold
) b
```

Comment: you need to wrap the `SELECT TOP 1 ... ORDER BY ...` in a derived query for the `UNION` to work

Comment: thank u so much for your help